# Can not set Stylesheet for buttons in QMessageBox

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qpushbutton, qmessagebox

I don't know where I am wrong with setStyleSheet, but the result is not as I want. Could you guys tell me where the problem is?

```
if (!closedialog) {
        closedialog = new QMessageBox(this);
}
closedialog->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
closedialog->setWindowTitle("Hello");
closedialog->setText("This is an example message.");
closedialog->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
closedialog->button(QMessageBox::Yes)->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{border-image: url(:/dptv/graphics/PTV_Button_yes.png);}"
    "QPushButton:hover{border-image: url(:/dptv/graphics/PTV_Button_yes_mouseover.png);}");
closedialog->setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, "");
closedialog->setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, "");
int click = closedialog->exec();
if (click == QMessageBox::Yes) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the problem

```
closedialog->button(QMessageBox::Yes)->setObjectName("Yes");
setStyleSheet("QPushButton#Yes{border-image: url(:/dptv/graphics/PTV_Button_yes.png);}"
"QPushButton#Yes:hover{border-image: url(:/dptv/graphics/PTV_Button_yes_mouseover.png);}");
```

And I forgot to add image into .qrc